# Maximal monotone operators - Zeidler's book - question about the proof.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bochner-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

I have a problem with understanding the proof of the proposition 32.10 which I enclose below (E. Zeidler II B). I cannot understand why Zeidler gets from (28)

$$\int_{0}^{T}\varphi'(t)v(t)+\varphi(t)w(t)dt=0$$
for all $\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(0,T)$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as a linear functional, i.e., a member of $V^{*}$, the action of which on every element of $V$ gives zero. Such a linear functional must then be zero itself.

Comment: I treat it as a member of $V^*$, but still don't know how from inequality which contains additionaly $\langle w, v \rangle_{X^*\times X}$ we have zero functional.

Comment: Equation (28) contains the action a linear functional. Moreover, he tells you one line after that by symmetry of $\langle a,b\rangle $you deduce two reverse inequalities in (28) and thus that it equals to zero. He explicitly writes the action of $V^*$ on $V$. Think about it a minute, and it will become clear.